# SF fantasy anthology that contains these two stories: one about a shapeshifting clown, and another about a cyborg working in a brothel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to find details that will help me track down a SF fantasy anthology from the 90s or early 00s.It may have been in the "The Years Best Science Fiction and Fantasy" series, or similar. The cover featured a desert like landscape, with a blue sky with multiple moons.

All I remember of the contents are details of two of the stories- which were brilliantly written, making me hope they were by well known authors:

A travelling clown/ performer who can change their material composition; the name of the story is the name of the clown, I think. They change into a rope, and various other objects before being run out of town by a baying mob, and hide by turning into a puddle of water.

Told from a first person narrative, the protagonist is miner/geologist who undergoes extensive reconstruction following an accident, and is subsequently employed in a strange alternative brothel, where clients pay to spend time with them, including switching them on and off. The narrator briefly describes some of their body modifications- they involve porcelain, clockwork, and brass, and mentions other colleagues (human and alien?) whose appearance or augmentations draw niche clientele.

Any help, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!